# Android GridView with ImageView and TextView don´t show well

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

Hi I have a problem displaying my Gridview. I searched many sites and here on StackOverflow but took several days without finding the solution.

I leave here my xml (listado.xml) code where is gridview:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
   >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_release"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clipChildren="true"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:numColumns="2" 


    >

    <!-- android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform" 
    android:verticalSpacing="1dip"-->



</GridView>
```

The xml file with textview and imageview (grid_release.xml):

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#DC0000"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/rls_img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"


     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rls_txtTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="Titulo" />
```

Also leave the code of ImageAdapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View grid;

    if(convertView==null)
    {
        grid = new View(context);
        grid = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_release, null);



    }else{
        grid = (View)convertView; //imageView=(ImageView)convertView;

    }


    ImageView rlsimg = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.rls_img);
 rlsimg.setImageDrawable(LoadImageFromURL(GridViewConfig.getResim_list().get(position)));
    TextView rsltxt = (TextView)grid.findViewById(R.id.rls_txtTitle);
    rsltxt.setText("Adpt00"+position);
    return grid;
```

Thanks for help!!!

Comment: So what is your problem? I mean, what does it show now?

Comment: Sorry, did not let me attach pictures by reputation. My problem is that the elements of the sample gridview disordered me. For example shows me pictures and texts about higher than others. When should all be in alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solve my problem:

Metodo GetView of ImageAdapter

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View myView;

    if(convertView==null)
    {

        LayoutInflater li = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        myView = li.inflate(R.layout.grid_prueba1, null);
        myView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100,100));
        myView.setPadding(5,5,5,5);


    }else{

        myView = (View)convertView;

    }

    ImageView img = (ImageView)myView.findViewById(R.id.img2);
    img.setImageDrawable(LoadImageFromURL(GridViewConfig.getResim_list().get(position)));
    TextView txt = (TextView)myView.findViewById(R.id.txt2);
    txt.setText("Adept0000"+position);

    return myView;
}
```

But now I have another problem, textview displayed within the image. I want this text below the image. I'll have to open another query.